# Why is my matrix inverse calculation with Cholesky decomposition slower than my LU version?

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-decomposition

I have already confirmed that my Cholesky decomposition routine is indeed at least 50% faster than the Crout's LU decomposition (for square, symmetric, positive definite matrix). However, I'm losing the gains afterward when I produce the actual inverse, so I must be doing something simple wrong.

The LU routine creates a combined lower and upper factor matrix, and then sends this to a solving routine which looks like it is doing both forwards and backwards substitution.

My Cholesky routine produces the single lower triangular factor $L$. I then compute the inverse $L^{-1}$ using forward substitution only. I then create the transpose $(L^{-1})^T$ and finally compute the inverse $A^{-1} = (L^{-1})^TL^{-1}$. The problem is this routine overall ends up being slower than the LU version overall. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could be anything. Which language are you using could be a good first question.

Comment: C#. It could be extra array allocations when I do the transpose and then the product. Maybe I can do this "in place." Can anyone confirm that my overall approach following the Cholesky decomp is the expected way to get the inverse?

Comment: I think inverse of a triangular matrix should not take much time if you are doing it right. Yes maybe array allocation or garbage collection or that you create new objects unnecessarily. In place would be best.

Comment: Using in-place multiplication, I was able to get the Cholesky method down to 80% of the LU method's time. Not as good as I was hoping for, but at least a sane result.